# How to start up your .NET program from web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, browser, application-start

Could you provide example of JavaScript function for starting up application installed on your computer from a web browser (eg google chrome 4). It particular if .Net APPs have any special simplifying this process apis of out there are some libs for such staff, please share link with us.

so how to create and store in run on  start up programs a small local server which would handel some local urls like http://localhost/maAppServer/MyAppCalculator/Start for starting apps that have written in its config file their names and local urls on install?

So how to start up your C# .NET app\program from web browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe its possible in Chrome, starting an EXE on a users computer could be considered a security violation. Some ActiveX, and file:// links in internet explorer may work. Also, OneClick deployment may do something similar to what you are after (not exactly though I don't think, and I believe they require an add-in which may not be available for Crhome) http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm

Comment: RodH257 is right, it is not possible and it would be a major security flaw if it was.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're asking for. You can start an application on your computer just by linking to it in the HTML page. However, if you need to pass data to it, then it's a different matter altogether, although it's still simple.

An example is what www.nexon.com does with it's MMORPG, MapleStory. You log on to the website, and the web page starts the game after the authentication. Another example would be the magnet links on file-sharing sites.

You need to create a protocol handler, it can be in any language like C++/C# and register it on the client's computer. Like so - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

Then, just use the protocol you built to pass on whatever data necessary. You can add a link that can be clicked, a button, Response.Redirect() from the server, whatever you like.