# How to launch my windows universal app with button click in browser?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I have developed one windows universal application and one web application. I known that I could launch my uwp app that has scheme name(`myapp:`) via [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) method in the source uwp app or `Run` dialog box.

But I could not found any approach to launch uwp app within browser. I know this is feasible. 
[image]

I want open windows universal app form web application. Can give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start up your .NET program from web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981163/how-to-start-up-your-net-program-from-web-browser)

Comment: you are not understanding my question. Do you know about WUP. How you will click down mark.

Comment: So you don't want to run your application when the user clicks something in a web browser? (I didn't downvote btw, although your question does seem rather vague / broad)

Comment: yes You can also launch custom URI schemes too.. i need help on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

> i want open windows universal app form web application.

You could open your UWP app that registered to become the default handler for a [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) (URI) scheme name.

And then, you could create a simple html page like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App36</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <div>
        <a href="ms-windows-store:">OpenApp</a>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click `OpenApp` label in bower that runs in the window 10 operation system, it will launch the store app. You could replace `ms-windows-store:` with your app Uri protocol name(eg:`myapp:`)to launch your app.